# Discover mobile devices in proximity to exchange information

Tags: android, ios, api, cross-platform, proximity

I've been looking for a solution that will allow me to see when two devices are in close proximity to initiate exchange of information. As simple as it sounds, I'm still not able to find a solution that I can implement to the app I am working on, since everything related to time and location is covered by patents and my client is really big on not messing with that.

Initially I was working with Bump's API, which worked ok but after they got acquired by Google  their API is going away so there's no point on using it anymore.

I've seen other companies like Airlike, ProxToMe, Shoutr, Hoccer ans Xsync that have viable solutions but unfortunately they don't have APIs that I could use.

Do you know of a cross-platform API or another solution that could help me see the devices?

Thank you very much everyone. I am running out of time and my resources are limited but I'm hoping someone hear can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Brainiac. I'm working at shoutr labs and we do have a proximity finder for Android. But no API, yet. We are currently working on a bluetooth solution to discover nearby devices in close proximity without Internet. Let me know if this could help you... –